Regarding the government signature on the front page of a passport
In my Indian passport there is no signature in the front, which is the government signature of India. The last time while travelling they stopped me in immigration saying that this is actually not an original and maybe it’s a fake and finally they asked me to resolve it.
However, I live in Australia. Is there an option to rectify this issue from here so that there will be no problem when I go to India again? They gave me a last chance to rectify saying that they will be not allowing me next time.

Consulates handle passports for citizens living abroad. Did you contact the Indian consulate in Australia (there are 4 of them). What did they say?

I've never heard of a "government signature" before. Are you sure that the missing signature isn't your own? I've never seen an Indian passport, but my (US) passport has a space on the first page marked "Signature of bearer" where I was required to sign the passport after receiving it. It might be helpful to include a picture of the page where they said the signature was supposed to appear (obscuring any sensitive information, of course).

Online photos of Indian passports (example) show the bearer's own signature on the photo page, and a stamp and signature of some passport official on the facing page.  Which of these is missing on yours, or are you talking about something else again?  (But regardless of what it is, if the immigration officers don't like it, you should get it corrected or replaced, and as mentioned the Indian consulate is the place to go for that.)
