stamp and signature is missing in the passport
I received Indian passport without stamp and signature on the first page. what should I do now in order to get stamp and signature from the regional passport office. is there any procedure to apply again to get the stamp and signature in my passport?

Is it ECR or non-ECR?

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/188766/regarding-the-government-signature-on-the-front-page-of-a-passport

I believe you should contact the authority which issued it. Let us know what they say.

That's probably a mistake. The passport I renewed around 3 months back has stamp and signature.
You have to contact the passport office which issues the passport and get it corrected.

Was your passport an e-Passport? It’s unclear to me if all currently issued passports are or only some of them.

Not e passport. AFAIK, India didn't roll out e-passports for ordinary passports.

Wiiipedia says they started limited roll out for ordinary passports this year: “the testing of the project of e-Passports is under way at Regional Passport Offices in Bhubaneswar and Nagpur”.

According to the Q.No. 57 of the FAQs of the passportseva website, it seems the stamp has been discontinued for the Non-ECR passports.

The practice of placing the Non-ECR (ECNR)/ECR stamp has been
discontinued. Instead of placing stamp, only ECR status is printed on
the top of the last page of the passport. If nothing is printed on
last page in this regard, it is a Non-ECR passport.


I don’t think this is the stamp OP is talking about. OP is talking about the stamp and signature on the page with the text beginning “These are to request and require…”, as visible here for instance (the page with this text and stamp has moved within the passport depending on the version). Note that I’m not sure the stamp and signature are still added in the most recent versions, but OP in the question I linked to in comments had issues with the missing stamp and signature.

Stamp and signature is there for the passport I renewed 3 months back.
